# Add mongo in my docker project I got ref error

Tags: mongodb, dockerfile

I need to add mongo in my docker project, so in file Dockerfile.yml I added mongo packages:

```
  FROM php:8.1.6-apache
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    mc \
    git-core \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    curl \
    gnupg2 \
// I ADDED THIS LINE
    && git clone https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository 'deb https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian buster/mongodb-org/6.0 main' && \
    mongodb-org-tools \


    build-essential \
    libnotify-bin \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    locate \
    # composer \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git && \
    cd node  \
    && git checkout v14.18.0 \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

// I ADDED THIS LINE
    RUN pecl install mongodb
    RUN echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini


    RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

But running command :

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

I got error in the end of long output :

```
Setting up librsvg2-dev:amd64 (2.50.3+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libmagickcore-6.q16-dev:amd64 (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3) ...
Setting up libmagickwand-6.q16-dev:amd64 (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3) ...
Setting up libmagickwand-dev (8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.2+dfsg-1+deb11u1) ...
Cloning into 'server-6.0.asc'...
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
fatal: repository 'https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc/' not found
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2
```

Looks like link

```
https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc/
```

is invalid (I found this mongo adding part script in net)...

Which is valid format of it ?

**Updated parameter :**

I replace command with wget -qO , but have an error in long output :

```
$ docker-compose up -d
  Building web
  [WARNING]: Empty continuation line found in:
               RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2     wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc     build-essential     libnotify-bin     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git &&     cd node      && git checkout v14.18.0     && ./configure     && make     && make install
  [WARNING]: Empty continuation lines will become errors in a future release.
             Step 1/13 : FROM php:8.1.6-apache
               ---> af944036d594
             Step 2/13 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2     wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc     build-essential     libnotify-bin     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git &&     cd node      && git checkout v14.18.0     && ./configure     && make     && make install
               ---> Running in 43469c40032e
  Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
  Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
  Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
  Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [216 kB]
  Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
  Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [14.6 kB]
  Fetched 8622 kB in 2s (4302 kB/s)
  Reading package lists...
             E: Command line option 'O' [from -qO] is not understood in combination with the other options.
             ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2     wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc     build-essential     libnotify-bin     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git &&     cd node      && git checkout v14.18.0     && ./configure     && make     && make install' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Invalid option ?

**Updated parameter #2 :**

I added  curl  with mongo at the top of my Dockerfile.yml and installing mongodb-org below:

```
  FROM php:8.1.6-apache

    RUN curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \

    RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org

   ....
    RUN pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

But I got error :

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y mongodb-org' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Some commands missed ?

**Updated parameter # 3:**

On page https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ I read :

> The following instruction is for Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal).
>
> Create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list file for
> Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal):
>
> echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu
> focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list

So I modified Dockerfile.yml :

```
  FROM php:8.1.6-apache

    RUN curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc


    RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list



    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet \
    python \
    ...
    
    
    RUN apt-get install -y mongodb-org
        
    ...
```

But I got next error :

```
Step 1/14 : FROM php:8.1.6-apache
 ---> af944036d594
Step 2/14 : RUN curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35860e06b960
Step 3/14 : RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
 ---> Running in 429354b0f0e8
deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse
Removing intermediate container 429354b0f0e8
 ---> 29a893b3932d
Step 4/14 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     apt-transport-https     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2     build-essential     libnotify-bin     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git &&     cd node      && git checkout v14.18.0     && ./configure     && make     && make install
 ---> Running in b0e828050374
Get:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease
Get:4 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [218 kB]
Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
Get:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release [3094 B]
Get:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release.gpg
Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [14.6 kB]
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A26B1AE64C3C388
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/6.0 Release' is not signed.
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends --quiet     python     apt-transport-https     libfreetype6-dev     libwebp-dev     libjpeg62-turbo-dev     libpng-dev     libzip-dev     nano     mc     git-core     libmagickwand-dev     curl     gnupg2     build-essential     libnotify-bin     openssl     libssl-dev     libgmp-dev     libldap2-dev     netcat     locate     && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git &&     cd node      && git checkout v14.18.0     && ./configure     && make     && make install' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

What is wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
git clone https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

with

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

or

```
curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

in you Dockerfile.yml line 17

( usually wget is installed by default in most linux distributions , but if it is not , you may easily install before the line 17 in the apt-get install line , same apply to curl  )

PS:

#1 question answer:

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc
```

#2 question answer:

```
apt-get install apt-transport-https
```

#3 question answer:

```
 wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Please read Updated parameter

Comment: You must add only wget in install line , not wget -q0 ...

Comment: I used curl format :     RUN curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc   But not sure : as in this command I upload mongo, have I also to install it?

Comment: The curl command is getting the repo key only so you can add the repo later to your apt repos , having the repo configured later you can install the mongo packages if you need them

Comment: Please look at Updated parameter #2

Comment: you are not having the repo most probably  , check the exact install steps here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ , before apt-get update you will need to add the mongoDB repo for your distribution ...

Comment: also for accessing the https repo you will need to install: apt-transport-https

Comment: Please look at Updated parameter #3

Comment: add the "| apt-key add -"  at the end of your wget asc line so you can store the repo key to your apt key storage